# F# type Statisitic

Tags: list, types, f#

I created a Type Statistics and I have to return every value = 0 in the type Statistics. I don't know how to return the Type Statistics. I only know how to return an 'a list'. Here is the Type:

```
type Statistics =
{ mp: Nat  //--> should get 0
  w: Nat   //--> should get 0
  d: Nat   //--> should get 0
  l: Nat   //--> should get 0
  gf: Nat  //--> should get 0
  ga: Nat  //--> should get 0
  gd: int  //--> should get 0
  pts: Nat //--> should get 0
  ag: Nat  //--> should get 0 }
```

Here is what I tryied:

```
let zeroStats: Statistics =
    Statistics
    |> List.map (fun x -> x = 0N)
```

Comment: You might want to look into the Reflection package (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/microsoft.fsharp.reflection-namespace-%5Bfsharp%5D). Alternatively implement a member that combines the others into a list (easy way).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a value of a record type, you need to use the following syntax:

```
let zeroStats =
  { mp = 0N  
    w = 0N   
    d = 0N   
    l = 0N   
    gf = 0N  
    ga = 0N  
    gd = 0
    pts = 0N 
    ag = 0N  }
```

There is no simple way of doing this using an iteration or something like `List.map`. You just have to explicitly set the value for each of the fields. (If this was a problem, you could represent your data differently, perhaps as a list of key value pairs.)

As mentioned in the comments, you could do this using F# reflection, which is a mechanism that inspects the type structure at runtime and lets you manipulate that. However, this is a more advanced method that you probably do not need here.